# How is Django able to grant reserved port numbers?

Tags: python, django, port

Using this command

> `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

we can host a Django server locally on any port.So a developer can use reserved and privileged port numbers say

> `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:80`

So, now I am using port 80 defined for the HTTP protocol.

So, why does this not raise any issues and how is this request granted ?

Comment: If there is no webserver (nginx, apache etc.) or any kind of application running on port 80, you can of course use that port as well.

Comment: Listening to port below 1024 requires root permissions on many operating systems.

Comment: if I am accessing port 80 of a webserver then can I use the same port to run an application on that port?

Comment: There is a big warning in the runserver docs that say it is only to be used for development, not production

Comment: Its not about develoment or production but more about reserved ports in both cases that shouldn't be allowable.

Comment: But your question becomes mute, if you're defining what port you want with this arg then you must have some idea of what is usable.  It is never designed to be a stable running server

Comment: Thanks,  so we can say that if we define a port number to a rserved port such as tcp, http or any other of the 1024 then it shall not be a stable running server?

Comment: Do not say or assume. Read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#runserver I'm not yelling, just quoting: 'DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING.'

Comment: That said, all is fine when you develop your application and want to use some insecure or reserved port. Django will not stand in your way because Django isn't a server. It does not want to be a web server. It doesn't enforce web server 'rules' on you. So picking any port number is fine by Django it simply doesn't care. It does not take any responsibility for port number as it is outside the scope of what a web framework is about.

Comment: Thanks @allcaps that really helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 80 has no magical meaning, it is not "reserved" or "privileged" on your server (besides most likely requiring root privileges to access, as others have mentioned). It is just a regular port that was chosen to be a default for http, so you don't have to write `google.com:80` every time in your browser, that's it.

If you have no web server running such as apache or nginx which usually listen to that port, then port 80 is up for grabs. You can run django runserver on it, you can run a plain python script listening to it, whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a proper server instead of Django's test server such as `nginx` or `apache` to run the server in production on port `80`. Running something like `sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` is not recommended at all.